# jQuery AJAX no error or success fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple contact form then I am POST'ing out from. I am trying to AJAX the data with jQuery but for some reason I am not getting any response from the handlers. Is this code correct?

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  $("#contactButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      clientName: $("input").eq(1).val(),
      clientEmail: $('input').eq(2).val(),
      clientMessage: $('textarea').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'email.php',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $("#contactButton").text("Thank You");
        $("input").val("");
        $("textarea").val("");
      },
      error: function(response) {
        alert("Error: Message Not Sent");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact">
  <input type="text" name="clientName" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="email" name="clientEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
  <textarea name="clientMessage" required>Message</textarea>
  <button id="contactButton">Contact</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you haven't stopped the default form submission (just the button click), so the page is actually unloading before the AJAX completes. To fix this you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` instead of the click of the button. Then you can stop the submission using `preventDefault()`.

Also note that you can use the `serialize()` method on the form to get the entered data instead of building your own object. Try this:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $("#contact").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $("#contactButton").text("Thank You");
                $("input").val("");
                $("textarea").val("");
            }, 
            error: function(response){
                alert("Error: Message Not Sent");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I had been doing manual serialization because I was looking for a problem and hadn't realized it was it the button vs form linking on the preventDefault. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var data = {
    clientName: $("input").eq(1).val(),
    clientEmail: $('input').eq(2).val(),
    clientMessage: $('textarea').val()
};
```

to

```
var data = {
    'clientName': $("input").eq(1).val(),
    'clientEmail': $('input').eq(2).val(),
    'clientMessage': $('textarea').val()
};
```

Comment: Both quoted and unquoted keys are valid and will make no difference in this case as there's no special characters in the key names

Comment: Ok sorry. I thought I had encountered an error because of this before. My bad