# ajax call succes or error functions wont execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This `ajax` call will not execute the success or error function. The call itself works.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var Temp = document.getElementById("inputTemp").value;
  var Light = document.getElementById("inputLight").value;
  alert("Submitted");

  $.ajax({
    url: "Collector.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      inputTemp: Temp,
      inputLight: Light
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("yes");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("no");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: have you included jquery.js in your page? what's the output of your console? is `myFunction` actually called somewhere in your program?

Comment: this js file is included in another html file which has jquery.js included. There is no output on the console and MyFunction is called in the html file. The post function works just fine its just the succes or error functions

Comment: Is there something in the network tag in the devtools to tell you what happened to the POST request?

Comment: did the `alert("Submitted");` got executed?

Comment: @Kristian alert("Submitted") does get executed

Comment: dunno how exactly you fire your method, but be careful to the document unloading trap : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286812/jquery-ajax-no-error-or-success-fired

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data type as json in ajax call.

Add `dataType:'json'`

```
$.ajax({
        url:"Collector.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            inputTemp: Temp,
            inputLight: Light
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("yes");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("no");
        }
      })
```